# Xcode 6.3 is not opening instruments anymore

Tags: xcode, instruments

I updated my Xcode from 6.2 to 6.3 and now instruments is not working anymore, it is requesting a template and it doesn't matter which one is chosen, it is not able to open it.
[image: A dialog after choosing an instrument]
[image: Dialog showing that it Xcode can't open the template]

It is happening with iOS 8.2 on an iPhone 6+, and with the simulator (ios 8.2 and 8.3).

**UPDATE** I also updated my phone to iOS 8.3 and tried with Xcode 6.4Beta and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Hi Can you please try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20890184/2058242

Comment: Didn't work, instruments if failing even if I start an empty single view project.

Comment: I have the very same issue. Tried to run from iOS 7.1 simulator to no avail...

Comment: Curiously it worked for me with another user on the same computer. I tried deleting ~/Library/Developer and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run this from a terminal:

```
sudo chmod a+rwxt /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments
```

to fixup permissions on that directory.

Source : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6441

I actually got the same problem with Xcode 7 and solved it by deleting instrument's default base temp directory, and I guess it was in this folder (/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments)

Comment: This should be tag as an accepted answer. It worked for me. Happened in Xcode 6.4

Comment: That's right, I got another error on Xcode 7 but the solution is the same.